# Error on calculating returns: the data format is not coverted properly

Tags: r, import, format

I basically downloaded the historical price of Bitcoin from Yahoo Finance.
After setting up the directory, I used the following script:

`dat[,6]` is the Adj Close price and `dat[,1]` is the date column.

```
dat<-read.csv(file="BTC-USD.csv",dec=".",sep=",",header=TRUE)
dat<-xts::xts(dat[,6],order.by=as.Date(dat[,1]))
bit.ret<-PerformanceAnalytics::CalculateReturns(dat,method="simple")
bit.ret<-bit.ret[-1,]
```

I get the error:

```
> dat<-xts::xts(dat[,6],order.by=as.Date(dat[,1]))
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

The data format is like this:

```
11/27/2018
```

What can I do?

Answer (score -1):

```
dat<-xts::xts(dat[,6],order.by=as.Date(dat[,1],"%m/%d/%Y"))
```

The explanation is this: as.Date function needed the correct format.
Because my data has the date format month/day/year, the correct input for the function is "%m/%d/%Y"

Comment: it's always best to include an explanation for any code to assist future readers. Better explanations also tend to get voted higher.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new here, I've only posted a few question I don't know why I stumbled over some rude people who downvoted my question. I know better now, but they should have said what was wrong about my post.

Comment: Hi @NicolaeSpataru; I didn't downvote your post but you need to understand that we expect you to familiarise yourself with posting rules prior to posting. There exist very clear rules on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what you can/should do in order to provide a [minimal reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Lastly, downvoting questions/answers does not mean being rude around here. It is the recommended way to provide feedback and to ensure some form of quality control for others.